# Is it possible to multi-class to Shaman and acquire the healing spirit power?

Tags: dnd-4e, healing, shaman

Is there anyway for a character to take Shaman as a multi-class feat, and acquire the Healing Spirit power?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mending Spirit](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=feat&id=1938) from primal power (p 148) gets you there. Although you already have to have taken Spirit Talker first. There is no other entry feat to Shaman.

> Mending Spirit [Multiclass Shaman]
>
> Prerequisite: Spirit Talker feat
>
> Benefit: You gain the shaman power healing spirit, but you can use it only once per encounter.

Comment: Yipes! Once per Encounter! That's way better than the once per Day heals all the other multiclassers get!

Comment: @Soulrift indeed, I suspect that's due to the higher feat tax associated with it.

Comment: makes me want to houserule a second feat for all the other multiclass leader feats, to up their once-a-day heal to once-per-encounter.

Comment: @Soulrift I'd give them access to another class feature in addition. Shaman has the second feat because they get access to a specific class feature with the first feat.